# No response from the HTTP GET (request with cookie)

Tags: java, android, cookies, response, http-get

I am setting cookies and then making a HTTP GET request but I am not getting any response. Could you help out ? I am not typing the exact URL for certain reasons.My code is:

```
 DefaultHttpClient httpclient2 = new DefaultHttpClient();      
               CookieStore cookieStore = (CookieStore) new BasicCookieStore();
                    if(cookieStore != null){
                        httpContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
                        httpclient2.setCookieStore(cookieStore);
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("URL");

                    try {


      HttpResponse protectedappresource = httpclient2.execute(httpget,httpContext); 


                    List<Cookie> cookies = cookieStore.getCookies();
                    Log.i("Cookie Store","Cookies size= " + cookies.size());
                    for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                        Cookie cookie1 = cookies.get(i);                           
                        Log.i("Cookie Store",""+cookie1.getValue());
                    }


                 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(protectedappresource.getEntity().getContent()));

                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");

                    String line = "";
                    String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
                     while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + NL);

                    }
                    in.close();

                    String result = sb.toString();
                    response = result;
                  System.out.println(" resource response " + result);
```

Comment: Are you sure that the link is good? eg, you have hit the URL in a browser and gotten a response. Or pinged the URL?

Comment: @Blaine Yes, it is works on a browser with a valid response, I suspect it has something to do with the cookies not being added to the HTTP GET, any idea ?

Comment: What type of response are you getting? 404? 400? If it's a cookie issue, you'll get something back. If not, then there is another issue.

Comment: It is working now, thanks. The issue was that I the cookiestore oobject was not added correctly to the HTTP GET.